# What's the Laravel way of sorting and filtering the View of my Posts by likes and comments past week or month

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, sorting, filtering

I am new to Laravel and was wondering if there is a magic Laravel way of sorting and filtering my View. Or do I create a DB query for each and every single combination?

Here is what I am trying to do:

Posts
- have likes
- have comments
- have ratings

The user should be able to Sort and Filter these by **weekly / monthly / all time**:

**Most**

- liked
- commented
- viewed

**Best**

- rating
- etc

Do I create a query for each option + each time period? Or whats the Laravel magic here?

Thanks for your help, much appreciated :)
MJ

Comment: That's really up to you. If there's a lot of posts, it's probably better to query each time. But if there won't be a lot of posts you might want to get them all and sort with Javascript, for better UX. Up to you in the end.

Comment: I would suggest doing this in your model or controller rather than the view. This is where the logic should be and better practice. You can use the help of Query Scopes for this.

Comment: query scopes was the key word, I think thats what I am looking for.